# iPad scrolls to top on tapping form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

I have just completed a responsive website **[www.kaplanindia.in](http://www.kaplanindia.in)**.

All elements of this site are working fine and compatible to all latest browsers. The problem occurs when it was tested on iPad. The contact page does not remain still at the same positio and on tapping the form elements like input box or submit button, the website scrolls to top with a white screen that faded out in few seconds.

I have searched here in this community but could not found its solution. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm using Google chrome and I wouldnt say the site is working fine. Seems a little broken on all aspects of the page - carousel, header etc... As the carousel isnt working it seems like maybe one of the bootstrap responsive css files are not getting pulled through.

Comment: I agree with @TomRudge. It doesn't seem to be loading this file: http://www.kaplanindia.in/js/jquery.min.map Also, you've got some html elements with duplicate IDs, which is likely to confuse any js that is trying to manipulate or interact with the DOM. For example, there are two divs with the  id "section-8"

Comment: Thanks Tom and Malcolm for your valuable responses. I will come back after fixing these issues.